# Calculate the different between the current time and a few days ago

Tags: php

I already inserted the time_of_start in my database as the following:

```
$time_of_start = strtotime(date('H:i:s a'));
```

after a few days I want to check if the current_time is the same_time_of_start or as maximum +2 hours, so I used the following code:

```
$time_of_received = strtotime(date('H:i:s a'));
if ($time_of_received > $time_of_start) {
  $extra_used_time_by_minutes = round(($time_of_received - $time_of_start)/60);
  if ($extra_used_time_by_minutes > 120) {
    $message = 'something here...';
  } else {
    $message = 'something else here...';
  }
}
```

I think there is something wrong here, Thanks for the help.

More clarification:
I'm making an application for rental car office, so I want to make sure that the customer will return the car at the same time in the first day he took it.

Also I will give him a free 2 hours, If he pass the free two hours I will count it as an extra day.
**For example:** he took the car at 4 PM and return it back after 3 days at 7 PM.
hope that is clear enough.

Comment: I think there's something missing from your question: What is the problem you encountered?

Comment: You only store time, not a date. That might be intentional, but there will be at least two hours in each day where you do not get any feedback, but probably most of the time.

Comment: As mentioned string conversion as not needed use time() then you can simply use **time - (60 * 60 * 24 * 2)** to calculate 2 days prior or simply **time - 172800** If you need two hows later just deduct another 720 from the seconds being deducted **172080**.

Comment: I'm making an application for rental car office, so I want to make sure that the customer will return the car at the same time in the first day he took it.Also I will give him a free 2 hours, If he pass the free two hours I will count it as an extra day, hope that is clear enough

Comment: Ive supplied an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using time. You don't need to extra calculations to determine whether the user is using the grace period. This should be very simple to adjust into your program to use the database/input fields instead of hard coded values.

This determines the return time and is used when the rental is placed into the database.

```
// set up the requirements
$grace = 720; // 2 hours in seconds
$days = 5; // Determines how many days the rental is for.

$rental_time = time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * $days) + $grace;
```

Because you set your timestamp with the return time instead of the start time the return is easier to manage.

```
$time_return_due = $time_from_database;

if (time() > $time_return_due) {
    // update the time stamp no added grace you already have it included
    $new_return_due = $time_return_due + (60 * 60 * 24);

    // apply new billing, send messages etc.
} else {
    // complete your returned 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, You gave me a way to manage my code, and it's working now.

Comment: No problem, In general if a code seems to be getting overly complicated you can often find a more efficient way in which to do it. In this case, less is more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php time function http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php instead of strtotime(date('H:i:s a'));

Also, what do you do with your $message ?

Comment: I dont think what he does with message alters the answer required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mahmoud Yhya try using `date("H")` to get current hour and `date("H",strtotime($time_of_start))` to get hour saved in database.

Comment: More clarification: I'm making an application for rental car office, so I want to make sure that the customer will return the car at the same time in the first day he took it.

Also I will give him a free 2 hours, If he pass the free two hours I will count it as an extra day. For example: he took the car at 4 PM and return it back after 3 days at 7 PM. hope that is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert time difference into minutes by using date function.

```
$diff = $time_of_received - $time_of_start;
$extra_used_time_by_minutes = date('i', $diff); // time in minutes
```

Comment: More clarification: I'm making an application for rental car office, so I want to make sure that the customer will return the car at the same time in the first day he took it.

Also I will give him a free 2 hours, If he pass the free two hours I will count it as an extra day. For example: he took the car at 4 PM and return it back after 3 days at 7 PM. hope that is clear enough.